# get data from mysql with multiple value

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data in url

sub_cat.php?s=1&os=3,1&brand=10,9&camera=19&storage=15,13&data=17

I have:

- operating systems with id 3 and 1
- brands with id 10 and 9
- camera with id 19
- storage with id 15 and 13
- data with id 17

i want to show mobiles having these specifications from sql database

```
if (isset($_GET['brand'])) {
          $sf_brand = $_GET['brand'];
          $brand_split = explode(',', $sf_brand);
          $sf_brand_len = count($brand_split);
          for ($ab=0; $ab < $sf_brand_len; $ab++) { 
            $append_sf_brand .= 'OR product.product_brand LIKE \''.$brand_split[$ab].'\' ';
          }
          $append_sf_brand_f = '('.substr($append_sf_brand, 3).')';
        }else{
          $append_sf_brand_f = '';
        }
        if (isset($_GET['os'])) {
          $sf_os = $_GET['os'];
          $os_split = explode(',', $sf_os);
          $sf_os_len = count($os_split);
          for ($ao=0; $ao < $sf_os_len; $ao++) { 
            $append_sf_os .= 'OR productspec.prospec_expspec_id LIKE \''.$os_split[$ao].'\' ';
          }
          $append_sf_os_f = '('.substr($append_sf_os, 3).')';
        }else{
          $append_sf_os_f = '';
        }
        if (isset($_GET['camera'])) {
          $sf_camera = $_GET['camera'];
          $camera_split = explode(',', $sf_camera);
          $sf_camera_len = count($camera_split);
          for ($ac=0; $ac < $sf_camera_len; $ac++) { 
            $append_sf_camera .= 'OR productspec.prospec_expspec_id LIKE \''.$camera_split[$ac].'\' ';
          }
          $append_sf_camera_f = '('.substr($append_sf_camera, 3).')';
        }else{
          $append_sf_camera_f = '';
        }
        if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
          $sf_data = $_GET['data'];
          $data_split = explode(',', $sf_data);
          $sf_data_len = count($data_split);
          for ($ad=0; $ad < $sf_data_len; $ad++) { 
            $append_sf_data .= 'OR productspec.prospec_expspec_id LIKE \''.$data_split[$ad].'\' ';
          }
          $append_sf_data_f = '('.substr($append_sf_data, 3).')';
        }else{
          $append_sf_data_f = '';
        }
        if (isset($_GET['storage'])) {
          $sf_storage = $_GET['storage'];
          $storage_split = explode(',', $sf_storage);
          $sf_storage_len = count($storage_split);
          for ($as=0; $as < $sf_storage_len; $as++) { 
            $append_sf_storage .= 'OR productspec.prospec_expspec_id LIKE \''.$storage_split[$as].'\' ';
          }
          $append_sf_storage_f = '('.substr($append_sf_storage, 3).')';
        }else{
          $append_sf_storage_f = '';
        }
        $sf_condition = '(product.product_id LIKE productspec.prospec_product_id) AND '.$append_sf_brand_f.' AND '.$append_sf_os_f.' AND '.$append_sf_camera_f.' AND '.$append_sf_data_f.' AND '.$append_sf_storage_f;
```

I have query:

```
$get_brand_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM product, productspec WHERE $sf_condition");
```

But it is not working well, so how I can show mobiles can anyone help me thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about *how* it's "not working well"?

Comment: `or die(mysqli_error($connect))` to `mysqli_query()`. and what does this have to do with mobiles?

Comment: mobile is a product that I have to call from database

Comment: Your code has a lot of issues. but first of all, can you please share with us what does `$sf_condition` variable contain for this particular sample data you've provided?